# How to remove/suppress TSSE converting FLAC to MP3 with FFmpeg?

Tags: windows-10, audio, ffmpeg, mp3, metadata

If I try to convert a *.flac soundfile to *.mp3 and use the command part `-map_metadata 0` (or even `-map_metadata -1`) I always get an additional ID3tag entry TSSE or ENCODERSETTINGS with the content Lavf57.49.100.

I tried to remove this unwanted tag with `-metadata TSSE=""` or `-metadata encoder=""`but it doesn't work. According to [Jon Hall](http://jonhall.info/how_to/create_id3_tags_using_ffmpeg), this should work, but not for me...

How can I copy only the existing metadata tags from the *.flac file without any additional information from the FFmpeg conversion?

FFmpeg-version: N-81664-g6f062eb

Comment: Why do you want to prevent that?

Comment: I don't like software who forces me to accept advertising and additional worksteps - with additional software - to get the expected result.